# How to pass extential type of tuple to invariant generic function?

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, covariance, existential-type

I have an extential type of tuple, and I want to pass it to a generic function (I use ClassTag in this example but it is a custom type class with invariant type parameter):

```
type TC = (ClassTag[T], Option[T]) forSome {type T}
def foo[T](ct: ClassTag[T], o: Option[T]) = {}

val tc: TC = (classTag[String], Option[String](null))
foo(tc._1, tc._2)
```

This gives me error:

> error: type mismatch;
>    found   : scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]
>    required: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Any]
>   Note: T <: Any, but trait ClassTag is invariant in type T.
>   You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
>          foo(tc._1, tc._2)

I wanna ensure the type of two parameters `ct` and `o` uses the same parameter type T and I thought extential type should ensure this, but it does not seem to work.

However if I don't use tuple and only use ClassTag, it works fine:

```
type TC = ClassTag[T] forSome {type T}
def foo[T](ct: ClassTag[T]) = {}

val tc: TC = classTag[String]
foo(tc)
```

So the previous error of ClassTag invariance does not make sense.

Why does it not work when I use a tuple? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `val tc: TC = classTag[String], Option[String](null))` `tc._1` has type `ClassTag[_]` (which is different from any `ClassTag[T]` e.g. `ClassTag[Any]` because `ClassTag` is invariant), `tc._2` has type `Option[_]`, which is the same as `Option[Any]` because `Option` is covariant

```
implicitly[Option[_] =:= Option[Any]]
implicitly[Option[Any] =:= Option[_]]
```

> An existential type  `forSome {  }` where  contains a clause type `[tps]>:<:` is equivalent to the type `′ forSome {  }` where `′` results from  by replacing every covariant occurrence of  in  by  and by replacing every contravariant occurrence of  in  by .

https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#existential-types

So in

```
def foo[T](ct: ClassTag[T], o: Option[T]) = {}
foo(tc._1, tc._2)
```

we have the type mismatch. `Any` and `_` (aka arbitrary `T`) are different types.

Try to use universal quantification rather than existential

```
type TC[T] = (ClassTag[T], Option[T])
def foo[T](ct: ClassTag[T], o: Option[T]) = {}

val tc: TC[String] = (classTag[String], Option[String](null))
foo(tc._1, tc._2)
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Accepted as an answer, but I got other problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733018/how-to-return-wildcard-generic