# How to return wildcard generic?

Tags: scala, typeclass, covariance, existential-type, singleton-type

I have a type alias with parameter and I would like to return the instance of different parameter types from a method:

```
type TC[T] = (ClassTag[T], Option[T])

def gen(x: Int): TC[_] = x match {
  case 0 => (classTag[Int], Option[Int](0))
  case _ => (classTag[String], Option[String](""))
}
```

This does not work and gives me error:

> error: type mismatch;
>           found   : (scala.reflect.ClassTag[_ >: Int with String], Option[Any])
>           required: TC[*]
>              (which expands to)  (scala.reflect.ClassTag[*$1], Option[_$1]) forSome { type _$1 }

And I tried to use `Any` instead of wildcard `_`, and it still does not work:

```
def gen(x: Int): TC[Any]
```

> On line 2: error: type mismatch;
>           found   : scala.reflect.ClassTag[Int]
>           required: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Any]
>          Note: Int <: Any, but trait ClassTag is invariant in type T.
>          You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
>          case _ => (classTag[String], Some(""))
>                             ^
>   On line 3: error: type mismatch;
>           found   : scala.reflect.ClassTag[String]
>           required: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Any]
>          Note: String <: Any, but trait ClassTag is invariant in type T.
>          You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to return specific type rather than existential. If you want `gen` to return different types depending on its argument then actually `gen` is a polymorphic function. Try the following approach with type class and singleton types.

```
type TC[T] = (ClassTag[T], Option[T])

trait Gen[X <: Int] {
  type Out
  def apply(x: X): Out
}
trait LowPriorityGen {
  type Aux[X <: Int, Out0] = Gen[X] { type Out = Out0 }
  def instance[X <: Int, Out0](f: X => Out0): Aux[X, Out0] = new Gen[X] {
    override type Out = Out0
    override def apply(x: X): Out0 = f(x)
  }

  implicit def default[X <: Int : ValueOf]: Aux[X, TC[String]] = instance(_ => (classTag[String], Option[String]("")))
}
object Gen extends LowPriorityGen {
  implicit val zero: Aux[0, TC[Int]] = instance(_ => (classTag[Int], Option[Int](0)))
}

def gen[X <: Int with Singleton](x: X)(implicit g: Gen[X]): g.Out = g(x)

gen(0) //(Int,Some(0))
gen(1) //(java.lang.String,Some())
```

---

Reasons are similar to those in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57731598/how-to-pass-extential-type-of-tuple-to-invariant-generic-function). `ClassTag` and `Option` have different variance.

Try

```
type TC[T] = (ClassTag[_ <: T], Option[T])

def gen(x: Int): TC[_] = x match {
  case 0 => (classTag[Int], Option[Int](0))
  case _ => (classTag[String], Option[String](""))
}
```

---

Even if you can't encode desirable property in types you still can check it at compile time with `check` in right hand side of pattern matching.

```
def gen(x: Int): (ClassTag[_], Option[_]) = x match {
  case 0 => check(classTag[Int], Option[Int](0))
  case _ => check(classTag[String], Option[String](""))
}

def check[T](classTag: ClassTag[T], option: Option[T]): (ClassTag[T], Option[T]) = (classTag, option)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the value x is not known at compile time. Why does neither extential (wildcard) nor Any work in  my case?

Comment: Why is that when we have an invariant generic type, we need to use `_ <: T`? What's the difference of that and something like `class Foo[+T]`?

Comment: @texasbruce `_ <: T` is the way to make invariant covariant. No difference. We could write   
`type ClassTag[+T] = scala.reflect.ClassTag[_ <: T]`
`def classTag[T: scala.reflect.ClassTag]: ClassTag[T] = scala.reflect.classTag[T]`
`type TC[T] = (ClassTag[T], Option[T])`

Comment: So both `type CT[+T] = scala.reflect.ClassTag[_ <: T]` and `type CT[T] = scala.reflect.ClassTag[_ <: T]` are the same and making CT covariant?

Comment: @texasbruce `scala.reflect.ClassTag` is invariant, `scala.reflect.ClassTag[_ <: T]` is covariant (with respect to `T`), `CT` in `CT[+T] = scala.reflect.ClassTag[_ <: T]` is covariant, `CT` in `CT[T] = scala.reflect.ClassTag[_ <: T]` is covariant as well.

Comment: So basically yes.

Comment: @texasbruce `CT` in `CT[+T] = scala.reflect.ClassTag[_ <: T]` **is** covariant and **is declared** as covariant. `CT` in `CT[T] = scala.reflect.ClassTag[_ <: T]` **is** covariant but **isn't declared** as covariant, so compiler will not allow `type CT1[+T] = CT[T]`.

Comment: Actually the code from your answer doesn't work... it says type mismatch

Comment: @texasbruce What is your Scala version? It compiles in Scala 2.13.0.

Comment: @texasbruce Existential types typechecks in different versions of Scala slightly differently. Generally, if `x` is a runtime value not every restriction can be encoded in types for compile time. Compiler infers that `gen` returns `(ClassTag[_ >: Int with String], Option[Any])`.

Comment: @texasbruce Also you can try approach with `check`. See update.

Comment: Still doesn't work in 2.12 though. Need to find something that works in 2.12

Answer (score 0):

It turned out because `Tuple4` type parameters are covariant: `Tuple4[+T1, +T2, +T3, +T4]`, it does not work well with invariant type classes like `ClassTag`.

I create a wrapper class that takes invariant type parameters:

```
case class TC[T](ct: ClassTag[T], o: Option[T])

def gen(x: Int): TC[_] = x match {
  case 0 => TC(classTag[Int], Option[Int](0))
  case _ => TC(classTag[String], Option[String](""))
}
```

Voila it works.